# Using submit50 in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide, cs50

I'm doing CS50 AI ( a course from harvard on EdX) and as a result been using submit50 (the command we use to submit assignments) in VSCode via the Windows Subsystem for Linux. Until I updated my IDE to the April update, submit50 used to ask my GitHub username and password in the the terminal itself similar to CS50 IDE.

After the April Update, it redirected me to the GitHub website for authentication and ever since then, I've been getting an error and can't figure out how to fix this.

I've tried re-install VSCode and submit50, upgrading submit50 and none of this has helped.

[The Error I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xz3Iz.png)

I deleted VSCode and Code from Appdata to try and delete all data but that did not help.

[Git Asking for permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAS3m.png)

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the new [automatic GitHub authentication](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_45#_github-authentication-for-github-repositories) introduced in VSCode version 1.45.

The temporary fix for this is to disable `Git: GitHub Authentication` in your VSCode settings either via the settings UI, or by adding the following line to your `settings.json`:

`"git.githubAuthentication": false,`

When you try to run `submit50` again, a popup prompt for your username and password will appear instead!

---

Alternatively, you can disable `Git: Terminal Authentication` in your VSCode settings either via the settings UI, or by adding the following line to your `settings.json`:

`"git.terminalAuthentication": false,`

Via this method, you'll get the login prompt for submit50 inside the terminal as per usual.